# Is there a clever way to calculate a mode of an online series without storing the series?

Tags: algorithms

My program's aim is to determine the correct time zone offset (GMT+k) as a series of numbers are fed to it. eg:

-4
+11
1
-4
-4

So, here -4 (the mode of the series) is the correct value.  But this requires storing the series then analyzing it and I do not have enough storage (RAM and FLASH) for this.  The running average can be calculated easily by storing the list size and the sum.  Is there a similar case for finding the mode?

Comment: All the answers suggested so far require RAM storage of an array albeit smaller one in case of the hash scheme (@amon).  The correct answer would not require that much ram.

Comment: If you know the correct answer why are you asking this question?

Comment: Consider a series consisting of all distinct numbers, concluded with a single duplicate number (e.g., `5 -4 2 6 5` has `5` twice, making it the mode). In order to identify this case, the only option is to store each number we have seen, in order to know that the final number is a repeat. At minimum, we must record that we have seen each particular number at least once, and record how many times we have seen it. You seem interested in an algorithm that does not store each number we have seen (e.g., "we've seen `n` instances of `5`"), which I think is provably impossible in the general case.

Comment: @user949300 I don't know the correct answer. Which is why I asked if a running mode can be calculated without storing the set.

Answer (score 6):

To calculate the mode from an unreasonably large data set (or stream) containing only a finite number of discrete elements (such as integers in a small range), use a table to count the occurrence of each element, where the element in the data set is the key in our table. We then go through the data set and increment that element's counter. At any point we can then determine the mode of the processed part of the data set.

Pseudocode example

```
 // all elements are integers in range a to b
 a = ...
 b = ...
 table = new Array(size: b - a, default: 0)

 // add items to the table
 for item in stream {
     table[item]++
 }

 // find the mode by sorting the table keys by their values
 mode = range(a, b).sortBy(item => table[item])
```

Instead of an array, a general purpose `Map` type (e.g. a hash map) will be needed if the elements aren't integers.

Comment: Hash maps also work better if the set of values is sparse.

Comment: Maps also work better if you don't know the range of possible inputs, or the known range is huge.  I really think Map should be the preferred approach in most cases and nearly downvoted this answer.

Answer (score 2):

The mode is the most commonly occurring single value. Fairly obviously, you just have to count occurrences of each value as it arrives and then at the end search the counts to find the largest. There are some interesting variations.

If and only if (a) the values are integers (b) you know the range in advance (c) you know the upper bound of the count then you can preallocate an array of suitable integers to hold the counts. That is probably the case in your particular situation.

If (b) is not true you can allocate an array and be prepared to resize it on the fly.

If (a) is not true you can use a hashed array (dictionary, map, etc) in much the same way, for some performance cost.

If (c) is not true (counts could exceed the range of int), you need to be prepared to allocate a second duplicate array to hold the overflows. And a third, and so on.

One final tweak. If you remember the value and highest count each time you update the array then you can avoid the final search.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to do this if the mode will appear at least 50% of the time:

```
def mode(numbers):
    mode, count = 0, 0
    for number in numbers:
        if not count:
            mode, count = number, 1
        elif number == mode:
            count += 1
        else:
            count -= 1
    return mode
```

If the mode doesn't have this property, then I can't think of a way other than to use an array of 24 counters, incrementing the correct one for each number encountered (`index = number + 11`), then looping through keeping track of the index with the largest count. The mode will then be `index - 11`.

If you can't use an array, then you could multiply in a prime (`number += 11; accumulator *= number * (number + 1) + 41`) for each number encountered, then compute the prime factorization and keep track of the index of the factor with largest exponent. The mode will then be `index - 11`. The problem with this is that a 64-bit integer can only store a few primes (8, maybe 10) multiplied together before overflowing.

Answer (score 0):

How often will a value be repeated?  If the answer is "rarely", you may be better off storing the entire series, as the various Map / counter options probably use more memory.  Only when there is a fair amount of repeats are they an advantage.